# What are the magento 2 events will triggers at simple product creation

Tags: magento2

Can you please list the events which are triggered at the time of simple product creation in magento2.

Recently I would learn about simple product creation and which are the database tables gets affected at the time of simple product creation.

So, now I just started to search for the simple product creation event, where those events are located and the purpose of those events.

Just gone through most of the links for finding a solution to my question.  But for my bad luck, I didn't get the exact answer.

can anyone help me to find the answer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the below URL for the list of all event and observer in magento2

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html

Comment: I already saw such link. But I need the exact event and observer for simple product creation. I'm new to magento, so I can't able to get the exact event and observer from this. Thanks